# Gmail pagination is missing , windows 8.1, google chrome- no way to see older messages

Tags: gmail

I have changed screensize as well and did CTRL F5 forced refresh and also checked settings

There isnt pagination button

So i can not see older pages

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears this is how the gmail feature to organize your inbox to show unread first. going back to the default inbox type will give you the pagination control.

to go back: gear/settings/inbox and then in the inbox type section switch "unread first" to "default"